# Am I using scanf incorrectly?

Tags: c

Each line of input is a line with a command followed by numbers (except in the exit case).

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  This segment is looking for the store command and then does the action store entails:

```
    char command[20];
    while(strcmp(command, "exit") != 0)
    {
        /*scans for command strings inputted*/
        scanf(" %s", command);
        /* handles store command*/
        if(strcmp(command, "store") == 0)
        {   
            memory[0] = 1;
            scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &startx, &starty, &finishx, &finishy, &number);
            for( i = startx; i < finishx; i++)
            {
                for(j = starty; j < finishy; j++)
                {
                square[i][j] = number;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  What have you tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: Its been a long time, but I avoided scanf like the plague. IIRC if you tried scanf %d and typed in something other than an integer the program would crash. IIRC I mostly used `fgets()` to read a line of input, validate it and then convert it as necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you are using it wrongly<sup>(a)</sup>. The line:

```
scanf(" %s", command);
```

has *no* bounds checking on the input. If someone enters more than 19 characters into your program, it will overflow the `char command[20]` and result in undefined behaviour.

The two major problems with `scanf` are:

- using it with an unbounded `%s` since there's no way to control how much data is entered. My favourite saying is that `scanf` is to scan formatted information and there's not much *less* formatted than user input.
- not checking how many items were scanned - it's possible to scan less than you expected.

If you want to do it right, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921). It uses `fgets` to get a line, protecting from buffer overflows and detecting problems.

Once you have the line as a string, you can safely `sscanf` it to your heart's content, since you *know* the upper bound on the length and you can always return to the start of the string to re-scan (not something easy to do with an input stream).

---

Other problems with your code include:

- The initial `strcmp` on an uninitialised buffer. It *could* actually be (arbitrarily) set to `exit` which would cause your loop not too start. *More* likely is that it's not a valid C string at all, meaning `strcmp` will run off the end of the buffer. That won't necessarily end well.
- No checking that all your numeric items were entered correctly. You do that by checking the return value from `scanf` (or `sscanf` should you follow my advice on using the rock-solid input function linked to here) - it should be five but entering `1 hello 2 3 4` would result in a return code of one (and all but `startx` unchanged).
- No range checking on input. Since `square` has limited dimensions, you should check the inputs to ensure you don't write outside of the array. That's both numbers that are too large *and* negative numbers.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> *Syntactically,* what you have is correct. However, from a actual semantic point of view (i.e., what you mean to happen vs. what may happen), there's a hole in your code large enough to fly an Airbus A380 through :-)

Comment: This was a very nice and informative response. I have voted to delete my response as I acknowledge yours was more useful.

Comment: Note that the correct format specifier is `"%19s"`; using `"%20s"` would be a mistake leading to overflow - and, since `command` is a local variable, it would be a stack overflow.

Comment: +1 For a nice answer: properly diagnosing the issue, describing the solution, and providing a link to good "model" are the trifecta. I wish all SO answers were like this.